# No Drill Down extension not working for summary reports

Tags: civireport

WP 5.3 civi 5.19.3 php 7 no drill down 1.1.2 (downloaded from github)

Love this extension & sad to lose it.
It works fine for detail reports - goes to contact record, but in summary report goes to detail report.

It used to work - sorry not sure when it stopped